What is the best view which can be used in this case?
I have a website where I want to display details as a supervisor, showing which teachers I supervise.
The page contains data about the teachers under this supervisor, and each teacher has a number of students they teach.
Each student has a number of subjects; let's assume that student A has different subjects from student B.
Of course, each subject for each student has details, in addition to attachments—let's say a portfolio, but not everyone has a portfolio.
If I want to display all this information on a single page, what is the best way to present this data?
Just to clarify, this is just an example, not a real project. I have tried the collapsible hide/show method, but the user said they want everything to be displayed and open; they don't want to see collapses.
I'm considering a vertical display method, as a table won't work due to the many columns.
I would appreciate your advice.

Welcome to the site! For us to be able to help, we need information about the users and their goals, since that drives design. Can you provide more information about the user's goals and tasks? It also seems you have talked to "users" (how does that relate to "not a real project", by the way?). What kind of study did you do: informal discussion, workshop with multiple users, formal Usabililty Test, ..?

... and also, perhaps: why did the user say such? "they want everything to be displayed and open; they don't want to see collapses." - why?
